# Undefined Array Key 'id' in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, key, undefined

I have an associative array in my controller.
The code is :

```
$patient_indoor[] = array (
 

);

$patient_indoor[] = array (
  array('id'=>$p->id,'name'=>$p->name,'mobile'=>$p->mobile,'due'=>$due),

);
```

When I try to print the value of the array in the blade file by the following code, It shows nothing. If I remove the @isset block, it says undefined Array key "id" . How can I fix the issue.

```
 @foreach($patient_indoor as $p) ?>
@isset($p['id'])
  <td>  {{$p['id']}} </td>
@endisset
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire  code while forwarding the data to view? `$patient_indoor`

Answer (score 2):

```
$patient_indoor[] = array (
  array('id'=>$p->id,'name'=>$p->name,'mobile'=>$p->mobile,'due'=>$due),

);
```

will return array as:

```
$patient_indoor[0][index]["id"]
```

Try this:

```
$patient_indoor = array (
  array('id'=>$p->id,'name'=>$p->name,'mobile'=>$p->mobile,'due'=>$due),

);
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `$patient_indoor[]` an array.

Replace it with `$patient_indoor` and it will be ok.